# Prove : To have a limiting point, a set should have at least 2 points.

Tags: analysis

Show that if M is a point set and M has a limiting point then M has at least 2 points in it. In another way of saying this, 1 element set can not have a limiting point. For a set to have a limiting point, the set should have at least 2 points.
All the help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Yes of course. And if the space is in addition Hausdorff, it must contain infinitely many points.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the point set and $p$ be the limit point. Construct a point interval around $p$. According to the definition of limit point, $M$ must contains another point that is different form $p$, hence $M$ has at least $2$ points.

Comment: What do you think about $\{a,b\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ ?

Comment: Downvoting this answer is ridiculous. +1

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a limit point of $M$, then for all neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $$M\cap (U\backslash \{x\})\neq \emptyset.$$

This is impossible if $M=\{x\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But I did not understand what this means ?M∩(U∖{x})≠∅.

Comment: @Masli: What is your definition of limit point ?

Comment: I don't know :-(

Comment: Are you joking ? How can you solve a problem if you ignore the principal definition ?

Comment: i do not know the orincipal definition with the symbols that you have used

Comment: M is a point set and p is a real number. Then p is a limit point of M if every point interval containing p  also contains a point of M different from p.

Comment: I see, then, replace "for all $U$" by for all $\varepsilon>0$, $M\cap (]x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon[\backslash \{x\})\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I genuinely appreciate your help and patience with me  but I did not understand what (]x−ε,x+ε[∖{x})≠∅ this statement stand for in words?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: (]x−ε,x+ε[∖{x})≠∅, I understand we are in the ε neighborhood of  x and something MUST not be empty set but ]x−ε,x+ε[∖{x}) represent?

Comment: @Masli: many countries use the notation $]a,b[$ to denote the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you TonyK then ∖{x} means?

Comment: without $\{x\}$

Comment: M∩(]x−ε,x+ε[∖{x})≠∅, it means that : the intersection of M with U which U is  in the neighborhood of ε with out x can not be equal to an empty space.

Comment: Sorry, I give up ! Look on google... I will erase my answer ! How can you stud an "advanced" thing if you even don't have the basis in set theory ?

Comment: Sorry :-( Surb ! This is my first class in analysis. I did not have a set theory class before.

Comment: Let denote $M'$ the set of limit point. By definition, $$M'=\left\{x\in \mathbb R\mid \forall \varepsilon>0, M\cap\Big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\backslash \{x\}\Big)\neq\emptyset\right\}.$$ Let $A,B$ and $C$ three set. $B\backslash C$ are the elements of $B$ that are not in $C$. (Some people also denote it $B-C$). Therefore $x\in A\cap (B\backslash C)$ mean that $x\in A$ and $x\in B\backslash C$, i.e. that $x\in A$, $x\in B$ but $x\notin C$. Suppose by contradiction that $M=\{x\}$ (in other word that $|M|<2$ where $|M|$ denote the number of element of $M$).

Comment: Then, for all $\varepsilon>0$, $$M\cap \Big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\backslash x\Big)\neq \emptyset,$$ but this is impossible because $M=\{x\}$ and thus $$M\cap \Big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\backslash \{x\}\Big)=\{x\}\cap \Big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\backslash \{x\}\Big)=\{x\}\backslash \{x\}=\emptyset.$$ Therefore, $|M|\geq 2$. Got it now ?

Comment: Now, I got it ! and Genuinely appreciate it :-). Have a great Sunday Surb !